# Ganglia spoof doesn't work when sending data to gmond

Tags: hadoop, spoofing, ganglia

I am using ganglia 3.6.0 for monitoring. I have an application that collect, aggregate some metrics for all hosts in the cluster. Then it sends them to gmond. The application runs on `host1`.

The problem here is, when setting spoof = false, ganglia eventually thinks this is metrics that only comes from `host1`. In fact, these metrics are generated by `host1` but for all hosts in the cluster.

But when setting spoof=true, I expect gmond will accept the host name I specified. But it gmond doesn't accept the metrics at all. The metrics is event not shown on `host1`.

The code I use is copied from GangliaSink (from hadoop common) which applied Ganglia 3.1x format.

```
xdr_int(128);               // metric_id = metadata_msg
xdr_string(getHostName());       // hostname
xdr_string(name);           // metric name
xdr_int(1);                 // spoof = True
xdr_string(type);           // metric type
xdr_string(name);           // metric name
xdr_string(gConf.getUnits());    // units
xdr_int(gSlope.ordinal());  // slope
xdr_int(gConf.getTmax());        // tmax, the maximum time between metrics
xdr_int(gConf.getDmax());        // dmax, the maximum data value
xdr_int(1);                 /*Num of the entries in extra_value field for 
                              Ganglia 3.1.x*/
xdr_string("GROUP");        /*Group attribute*/
xdr_string(groupName);      /*Group value*/

// send the metric to Ganglia hosts
emitToGangliaHosts();

// Now we send out a message with the actual value.
// Technically, we only need to send out the metadata message once for
// each metric, but I don't want to have to record which metrics we did and
// did not send.
xdr_int(133);         // we are sending a string value
xdr_string(getHostName()); // hostName
xdr_string(name);     // metric name
xdr_int(1);           // spoof = True
xdr_string("%s");     // format field
xdr_string(value);    // metric value

// send the metric to Ganglia hosts
emitToGangliaHosts();
```

I do specified the host name for each metrics. But it seems not used/recognized by gmond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this... The hostName format issue. The format need to be like `ip:hostname` e.g `1.2.3.4:host0000001` or any `string:string` is fine :-)